# How can I detect a subview being added anywhere in the view hierarchy (including subviews)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a framework for the other apps to use it. I want to find when the display presented to the user changes. These changes include addition and removal of subviews, scrolling down, adding text, etc. Is there a way I can directly check when the content presented on the screen is changing. Above question is a part of the problem.

Comment: I guess you can send notification the moment these changes are made, and add listener to that viewController you want it to listen to the changes.

Comment: Hi @Elena, Thank you for the reply. This is precisely what I want. It would be very helpful, if you could provide me with some pseudocode or even a structure and functions which could help me do it so that I can code it.

Comment: Ok @Adit, I supposed that you need to detect content changes in another controller but it`s not explicitly stated in your question. So could you please explain where exactly and for what purpose you need to know about changes made? This will make easier for me to help you

Comment: @Elena, I want capture user session in snapshots. My question basically is that if there exists an equivalent of ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener (android) in iOS.

Comment: >>if there exists an equivalent of ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener (android) in iOS<<                                 Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `viewDidLoad`?

That function called first time after all view loaded same as `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Answer (score -1):

After you explanations I would simply do something like this:

```
class MyViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func addSubview(){

        self.takeSnaphot()

    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView:UIScrollView){

        self.takeSnaphot()
    }


    func takeSnaphot(){

        //the code to take snaphots

    }
}
```

Comment: There might be apps where there won't be a ScrollView, just multi-paged application. In that case, I am not sure if just relying on this would help. Is there a way to find when addsubview or movetowindow functions are called in runtime?

Comment: This is just an example for the case that you need to know about events in the same controller. If you want another controller to know about events you send notifications